# GIT - Listing of All Files with Comments

Tags: git, jira

Can anyone let me know how to create list of all files exists in GIT repo with their commit comments so far.

I want to list all the files with their GIT commit comments which included JIRA issue id , is that possible ? If yes can anyone help me out on this as I am very new to both GIT and unix based commands. Thanks

```
------------------------
File Name |    Comments
-----------------------
Abc.java  |  CXXX-123, Added for feature a
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files itself don't have any comments.

The commits have a commit message. That is probably what you are talking about.

You can use something like `git log --oneline -- $filename` to see all the commits which touched that file together with its commit message.

If you need the last commit for each file you can use `git ls-files` to get all files and `git log -1` to get the last commit.

```
for i in $(git ls-files); do
   printf "%-30s %s\n" "$i" "$(git log -1 --oneline -- $i)"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its a good solution. by any chance can we get rid of hash number like "ca81a61" appears in commit message.

Comment: You can define the format of `git log`. See `git help log` for details.

Answer (score 0):

To find files in git with certain text in commit comments

e.g. listing all the files committed with text 'FIPTTRADECAP-10569' in the commit comments

```
for i in $(git log --oneline | grep FIPTTRADECAP-10569 | sed 's/ .*//');
do git diff-tree --name-only -r $i;
done
```